# How to get average direction from a set of 2d Vectors using linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-3.5

I have a `List<Vector2d>` where Vector2d is a simple point implementation like this: `public class Vector2d { public float X; public float Y; }`. I have selected two points a base (blue, `Vector2d Form;`) and a direction (orange, `Vector2d To;`) like this:

[image]

How to get all dots under the line formed by direction using LINQ or any other C# implementation (in a fashion that would be as short in code size as possible and will not require external (non out-of-the box) libraries?

Comment: If you are asking for a specific type of implementation (LINQ), does that imply that you have a different (non-LINQ) implementation? If so, please share that code. If not, why does it have to be LINQ?

Comment: Any implementation will do for me, yet I thought LINQ would be the shortest and simpliest to understend.

Comment: Please include sample data. You say, *"I have a `List<Vector2d>`"*. It would be helpful if you provided sample code that initializes this list, so we're all working with the same data.

Comment: @RufusL: provided Vector2d example code.

Comment: Thanks. If you have time, the initialization of the List with 12 points would be nice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do (can't test it):

```
var greenPoints = 
    allPoints.Except(new[] { redPoint, bluePoint })
             .Select(p => new Vector(bluePoint, p))
             .Where(v => {
                 var angle = AngleBetween(v, blueRedVector);
                 return angle > Math.PI / 2 &&
                        angle < 3 * Math.PI / 2; });
```

You may need to implement `AngleBetween`, its pretty trivial using vector's dot product.